# UIView animation always begins from current status

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

```
@interface ViewController
@property(weak) IBOutlet UIView *blackView;
@end
```

(1) First I tried to use animation block

```
- (IBAction) buttonHitted:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentStatus: NO];
    self.blackView.center = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width - self.blackView.center.x, self.blackView.center.y);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And the Animations ALWAYS begins from current status, and I can't find out why for long.

(2)Then I tried to use code block, it is the sad same.

```
- (IBAction) buttonHitted:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:0
                     animations:^(void)
                     {
                         self.blackView.center = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width - self.blackView.center.x, self.blackView.center.y);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
//Options to 0, indicating that UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState not setted
```

I just wanna know why the animation ALWAYS begins from current status. I checked the property of the view, it is always the last value of the current animation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out the reason behind it.

Animations for property(like UIView_ins.center and CALayer_ins.transform) **could be mixed together**, even you just changed one part of it, like just center.x

What's more, CAAnimation must set this property to YES, so the default CAAction for the transform must set this to YES too.

```
@property(getter=isAdditive) BOOL additive;
```

SO the new animation do not override the flight-in one, but just mixed them together.

To make sure it change UIView animation options to `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`

```
- (IBAction) buttonHitted:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^(void)
                     {
                         self.blackView.center = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width - self.blackView.center.x, self.blackView.center.y);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

You will see the lovely UIView standing there for a long time and did nothing, that is the symbol of mixed in linear way :)

While using the default EaseInOut options, it looks like the problem of `setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentStatus:`.